# Select the element right before the script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How would you select the first `input` in the code below without editing the DOM (using jQuery if needed)?

```
<input type="text"/> <!-- The element I want to select -->
<script>
    // Select the input above
</script>
<input type="text"/>
```

Please note there is an unknown number of inputs and script tags before and after this code sample, thus solutions like `$("input:eq(1)")` won't work.

The tricky part is to select the `input` placed right before the `script` tag from which the current JavaScript is being executed.

No need to ask me *why* I want to do this either, that's purely for the beauty of it, I want to do it without having to add random ids to my inputs if that's possible.

**Edit**
Here's why most of the answers won't work: http://jsfiddle.net/2WqfP/

Answer (score 9):

Scripts are always run as they are loaded, so the `<script>` tag that's running will always be the last one on the page. With pure JS you can get it like this:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
    currentScript = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
```

**Edit:** I got this wrong before. To get the input at this point, you want to get the preceding sibling, so you'd use [previousSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.previousSibling). Also, see thesystem's comment below about text nodes and a potential solution.

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
    currentScript = scripts[scripts.length - 1],
    input = currentScript.previousSibling;
```

You could also use jQuery:

```
var currentScript = $('script').last();
```

Once you have the script, you can get the preceding input easily:

```
var input = $('script').last().prev();
```

Comment: They're indeed run as they're loaded, but when they're appended at the beginning of the DOM (in a lightbox that works that way for example), we can't be sure the one being executed is the last one in the DOM.

Comment: @user1728278: A script being appended is a very different situation from that in the question. But if it is appended, then the code doing the appending must already know where the `input` is (since the `script` is placed relative to the `input`), and would therefore be able to select it.

Comment: @thesystem I guess I forgot that important point, but I hoped the *there is an unknown number of inputs and script tags before and after* bit would have made up for it. Regarding your proposition now, both the  `input` and the `script` tag are generated by PHP, when printing the above-mentionned lightbox. Thus your solution doesn't apply here :-/

Comment: If it's printed by PHP, that's server-side. From the client/JS point of view, it's the same as if it was just plain HTML. This should still work; have you tried it?

Comment: @@newtron: `.previousSibling` won't work because of text nodes. You could use `.previousElementSibling`, but you'd lose some browser support. @user1728278: If both are generated by PHP, and loaded dynamically, you would need a different approach. If you're saying that you want one piece of code that will work for any conceivable variation on your question, then you're not likely to find one. You need to write code specific to the the problem at hand. Variations on that problem will often require variations on the solution.

Comment: @newtron It's generated by PHP, then appended to a lightbox, and then tihs lightbox is prepended to the body. No way your solution can work,  since it's moved around the beginning of the DOM. Here's what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/2WqfP/

Comment: Why are you doing $('script')? That will select multiple script elements, which is not what Op is asking for.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a [jsfiddle showing my solution](http://jsfiddle.net/LS52K/1/).

```
$("input:last").val("test");
```

This works because when the script is reached, the input immediately preceding it is the last input to be created - the following `<input>`'s have not yet been added to the DOM. If you ran the code after page load (that is, in an `onload` even handler), this wouldn't work.

It's worth noting that I would personally prefer ids, so that you don't rely on inline JavaScript (which is usually a bad idea).

Comment: It would work in most cases, but unfortunately the code snippet is sometimes loaded in a lightbox, that is inserted at the beginning of the DOM. Thanks though!

Comment: About your last phrase, I would personally avoid both ids and inline JavaScript, but you know the drill, legacy code and everything...

Comment: @user1728278, If you have to do this after the page has been loaded, then I think any solution will have to include ids (or some more contrived form of marker which you can fit into your legacy code).

Answer (score 0):

Inline scripts are always run as they are parsed and the < script > tag only sees what above of him. 
Best solution on pure JS:

```
<input type="text"/> <!-- The element I want to select -->
<script>
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    var above_input = inputs[inputs.length - 1];
</script>
<input type="text"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("script").prev("input");
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
var input = $('script').prev();
```

http://api.jquery.com/prev/

Answer (score -1):

Native DOM solution:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var input = all[all.length - 2];
```

The `script` will be the last element on the page when it runs, so the `input` will be second to last.