# Add Class To Closest Element

Tags: jquery, closest

I'm trying to add a class to dynamically created objects, but there is something that is going wrong here. And I can't get it to work!

Any ideas?

```
<span class="status"><div class="like_button"></div></span>

 <script>  
   $(this).closest('span').find('.like_button').addClass('liked')
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

Thing is I am having a Facebook like button (created with the API not the regular one) inside each of the elements, and needs to check its status before I can add class "liked" or "unliked". So all the div's with class "item" is created in a PHP loop. And also I understand its not good to run the script several times in a loop. But I need to get further in the testings here :)

```
<div class="item">
 <span class="status"><div class="like_button"></div></span>
 <script>  
 $(this).closest('span').find('.like_button').addClass('liked')
 </script>
 </div>

 <div class="item">
 <span class="status"><div class="like_button"></div></span>
 <script>  
 $(this).closest('span').find('.like_button').addClass('liked')
 </script>
 </div>

 <div class="item">

 <span class="status"><div class="like_button"></div></span>
  <script>  
 $(this).closest('span').find('.like_button').addClass('liked')
 </script>
 </div>

 <div class="item">
 <span class="status"><div class="like_button"></div></span>
  <script>  
 $(this).closest('span').find('.like_button').addClass('liked')
 </script>
 </div>
```

Comment: `this` is the window ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: closest() looks for ancestors

Comment: How are you adding the object ?

Comment: `$("span").find(".like_button").addClass("liked");`

Comment: @tymeJV if there's only one 'span .like_button' in the page...

Comment: when this dynamic object getting add? are you using any event to add object?

Comment: This could be a fix to your code: `<span class="status"><div class="like_button liked"></div></span>`  Seems fair!

Comment: @tymeJV Thanks, but there are several span's and divs with class "like_button" in a loop. So now it just adds the class to all of them, not the current in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

When the code in the script tag will be running, the `<span>` will be the last loaded tag.

That beign said, you can do this :

```
$('span:last').find('.like_button').addClass('liked')
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/NRUuV/

Comment: Thanks Karl! But the thing is that I have multiple divs with class .like_button on the page. I made an update of the question if you care to have a look :)

Comment: @Kim That doesn't matter.  This will work.  Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443778/select-the-element-right-before-the-script-tag

Comment: @Kim if your DOM is exactly like that and nothing is added client side, it should still work.

Comment: see:  http://jsfiddle.net/NRUuV/1/

Answer (score -1):

Assuming $(this) is span:
    `$(this).next().addClass('liked')`

Comment: That's a bad assumption.  `this` is the `window` in the posted code.