# Add class to the closest element in a loop

Tags: jquery, closest

Thing is I am having a Facebook like button (created with the API not the regular one) inside each of the elements, and needs to check its status before I can add class "liked" or "unliked". So all the div's with class "item" is created in a PHP loop. And also I understand its not good to run the script several times in a loop. But I need to get further in the testings here :)

```
 <div class="item">
   <span class="status">
     <div class="like_button"></div>
   </span>
   <script>  
     $(this).closest('span').find('.like_button').addClass('liked')
   </script>
 </div>

 <div class="item">
   <span class="status"> 
     <div class="like_button"></div>
   </span>
   <script>  
     $(this).closest('span').find('.like_button').addClass('liked')
   </script>
 </div>

 <div class="item">
    <span class="status">
       <div class="like_button"></div>
    </span>
    <script>  
      $(this).closest('span').find('.like_button').addClass('liked')
    </script>
 </div>
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943671/add-class-to-closest-element

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're asking for or not.

```
$('.item').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.like_button').addClass('liked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you looking for is

```
$('.item .like_button').addClass('liked');
```

Comment: Thanks! But this code gives the class "liked" to all items with class like_button. But I only want to give it to the "closest" div with class "like_button"..